# Как перебрать объект и взять нужные значения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть объект в нем есть значения мне надо вытаскивать из него значения, с этим я справился вот так:

```css
var arr = {
      elem1: '0001',
      elem2: '0002',
      elem3: '0003',
      elem4: '0004',
      elem4: '0005'
};


$.each(arr, function(index, value) {

  if (value == '0003') {
    console.log( 'id найден ' + value );
  }

});
```

А вот если мне надо допустим вытащить несколько значений, к примеру 0003 и 0005? Писать еще условие? А если в объекте будет 100 значений и мне надо будет 10 определенных значений вытащить, писать еще кучу условий?
Есть какое то более изящное решение моего вопроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = {
      elem1: '0001',
      elem2: '0002',
      elem3: '0003',
      elem4: '0004',
      elem4: '0005'
};

var valuesToFind = ['0003', '0005'];

$.each(arr, function(index, value) {

  if (valuesToFind.indexOf(value) != -1) {
    console.log( 'id найден ' + value );
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Круто, работает! а вот этот метод .indexOf мне не знаком , пошел учить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

При использовании ES6 можно сделать так:

```js
const arr = {
          elem1: '0001',
          elem2: '0002',
          elem3: '0003',
          elem4: '0004',
          elem4: '0005'
    };
    
const valuesToFind = ['0003', '0005'];
const result = Object.values(arr).filter(val => valuesToFind.includes(val))

console.log("Source array", Object.values(arr))
console.log("Result", result)
```

Comment: А если не используете, то и `includes` работать не будет.

Comment: Проверил в MDN - действительно "не будет". Babel - учит быть ленивым :)
Я использовал бы полифилл.

Comment: Да на самом деле можно и простым `indexOf()` обойтись.